# Most recent date with multiple providers

Tags: sql

Below is my data:

```
MedicalRecordNumber edcdate wk  lastappt    facility    provider
----------------------  ----------  -----   ----------------------  --------------- ------------------------
255599  10/9/2014   37  3/8/2014 0:00   Women's Health  Prenatal Registration
255599  10/9/2014   37  6/12/2014 0:00  Women's Health  Tarcia
255599  10/9/2014   37  9/4/2014 0:00   Women's Health  Beaven
```

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
Select a.ownerid, p.patientprofileid, p.searchname, 
  max(a.EmrApptStart) as LastAppt, f.listname as facility, d.ListName as Provider
from Appointments a
  left join patientprofile p on p.PatientProfileId= a.OwnerId
  inner join DoctorFacility f on f.DoctorFacilityId = a.FacilityId
  inner join DoctorFacility d on d.DoctorFacilityId = a.ResourceId
where a.FacilityId in ('127','64') and p.MedicalRecordNumber = '00255599' and a.Status in ('Completed','Arrived')
group by a.OwnerId,p.patientprofileid, p.searchname,f.listname, d.listname
```

I am trying to get the most recent date and the provider they saw, when I don't include the Provider in the group by, I get the results I need, see below:

```
Select a.ownerid, p.patientprofileid as MRN, p.searchname, 
  max(a.EmrApptStart) as LastAppt, f.listname as facility
from Appointments a
  left join patientprofile p on p.PatientProfileId= a.OwnerId
  inner join DoctorFacility f on f.DoctorFacilityId = a.FacilityId
  inner join DoctorFacility d on d.DoctorFacilityId = a.ResourceId
where a.FacilityId in ('127','64') and p.MedicalRecordNumber = '00255599' and a.Status in ('Completed','Arrived')
group by a.OwnerId,p.patientprofileid, p.searchname,f.listname

MRN LastAppt    facility
----------  --------------  --------------------
255599  9/4/2014 0:00   Women's Health
```

If I include the Provider in my select statement, I get an error if I don't include it in the Group By clause.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are interested on top 1 record with Provider. In that case, you could add Provider to the `group by` clause, `select top 1 ....` and use `Order by a.EmrApptStart desc`

Comment: this worked wonderfully for one patient, but this is a join on a larger sql and will only pull for the one specific patient...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.PatientProfileId,
  a.MedicalRecordNumber,
  a.searchname,
  a.edcdate,
  a.wk , 
  b.lastappt, c.NextAppt, c.NextProvider
FROM
  (SELECT 
     PatientProfile.PID,
     PatientProfile.PatientProfileID, 
     PatientProfile.MedicalRecordNumber, 
     PatientProfile.searchname, 
     EDCDATE=case when isdate(max(RPTOBS.obsvalue))=1 then max(RPTOBS.obsvalue) end,
     WK=case when isdate(max(RPTOBS.obsvalue))=1 then 40-DATEDIFF(d,getdate(),max(RPTOBS.obsvalue))/7 end
   FROM   OBSHEAD OBSHEAD 
     INNER JOIN ((PatientProfile PatientProfile 
     INNER JOIN DOCUMENT DOCUMENT ON PatientProfile.PId=DOCUMENT.PID) 
     INNER JOIN RPTOBS RPTOBS ON (DOCUMENT.PID=RPTOBS.pid) 
     AND (DOCUMENT.SDID=RPTOBS.sdid)) ON OBSHEAD.HDID=RPTOBS.hdid
   WHERE  RPTOBs.hdid='8086' --and PatientProfile.PatientProfileID='255795'
   GROUP BY PatientProfile.PID,PatientProfile.PatientProfileID, PatientProfile.MedicalRecordNumber, PatientProfile.searchname)a

INNER JOIN
(SELECT DOCUMENT.PID, p.patientprofileid, LASTAPPT=DATEADD(day,max((DOCUMENT.CLINICALDATE)/1000000/3600/24),'1960-01-01')
FROM    DOCUMENT Inner join patientprofile p on document.pid=p.pid
WHERE       document.summary  like '%Prenatal%' and DOCUMENT.DOCTYPE = '1' --and p.patientProfileID='255795'
GROUP BY DOCUMENT.PID, p.patientprofileid) b 
ON a.pid = b.pid
INNER JOIN
(Select --TOP 1 
  a.ownerid,min(a.ApptStart) as NextAppt, d.listname as NextProvider
    FROM Appointments a
    INNER JOIN DoctorFacility d on d.DoctorFacilityId = a.ResourceId
    WHERE a.FacilityId in ('127','64') and  a.Status = 'Scheduled' and a.ApptTypeId in ('15','10','181','25','24','263','235','89','90') 
    --and a.ownerid = '255795'
    GROUP BY a.OwnerId, d.listname, a.ApptStart
--    ORDER BY a.ApptStart ASC 
    ) c
 ON a.PatientProfileID=c.ownerid  and b.patientprofileid = c.ownerid
WHERE EDCDATE>=cast(GETDATE() as DATE) 

GROUP BY
a.PatientProfileId,
a.MedicalRecordNumber,
a.searchname,a.edcdate,
a.wk, b.lastappt, c.NextAppt, c.NextProvider
```