# T-SQL Get most recent date while excluding a condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

This should be simple, but I'm struggling with it.

My table:

```
EmployeeID EmployeeType PayChangeDate
1          H            2/14/2012
1          H            3/8/2013
2          H            5/5/2012
2          H            6/6/2013
2          S            2/22/2014
```

My query:

```
SELECT
  EmployeeID
  , EmployeeType
  , MAX(PayChangeDate) AS CDate
FROM   EmployeesPayInfo
GROUP  BY EmployeeID
          , EmployeeType
```

My result:

```
EmployeeID EmployeeType PayChangeDate
1          H            3/8/2013
2          H            6/6/2013
2          S            2/22/2014
```

The problem is that I only want to see employees who are currently H. Employee 1 is fine since I'm only seeing his most recent pay change. Employee 2 started out as hourly but is now salaried, so I'm getting him twice when I actually don't want to see him at all. If I filter on H, I still get employee 2 on 6/6/2013.

I looked at [Most recent update with multiple providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895535/most-recent-date-with-multiple-providers) which was close, but didn't get me there since it returns only one record. He marked the answer as correct even though he said it was not what he wanted. None of the solutions I looked at had the exclusion that I need. I apologize if this is a duplicate, but none of my searches came up with the answer I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get only the rows where the last EmployeeType is`H`you can join a sub-query with the last dates per employee. If the last date in the inner query isn't a EmployeeType`H`the join won't match the rows.

```
SELECT
    EmployeesPayInfo.EmployeeID
  , EmployeeType
  , MAX(PayChangeDate) AS CDate
FROM  EmployeesPayInfo
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
       EmployeeID
     , MAX(PayChangeDate) AS CDate
FROM  EmployeesPayInfo
GROUP  BY EmployeeID
) MAX_DATES ON EmployeesPayInfo.EmployeeID = MAX_DATES.EmployeeID 
           AND EmployeesPayInfo.PayChangeDate = MAX_DATES.CDate
WHERE  EmployeeType = 'H'
GROUP  BY EmployeesPayInfo.EmployeeID
        , EmployeeType
```

This query would return the following with your sample data:

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeType CDate
----------- ------------ ----------
1           H            2013-03-08
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to vote this up, but it worked perfectly, eliminating all employees who are currently salaried.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.EmployeeID
      ,A.EmployeeType
      ,A.PayChangeDate
FROM (
      SELECT * 
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY PayChangeDate DESC) rn 
      FROM EmployeesPayInfo
      WHERE EmployeeType = 'H'
     )A
WHERE A.rn = 1
```

Comment: This looked promising, but it did not eliminate employee 2. It picks up his most recent PayChangeDate as an hourly employee, which it shouldn't. I have three employees that started as hourly but were changed to salaried and this query picks up all of them.